# netsh.exe keeps popping on Windows 10

Tags: popups, netsh

I am using Windows 10. The netsh.exe popup saying "The object already exists" shown in this image:

[image]

It keeps popping up from time to time. It pops up and goes away. While I am working or playing a game, suddenly this popup starts to flash for about 7 times. How to fix this?

> Blockquote

Comment: Something that has been installed on your system is causing nets.exe to be executed, however, it’s failing to execute properly. [Sounds like a network configuration error.](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/error-message-when-adding-ip-adress.345425/)

Comment: @Ramhound yea makes sense. Any idea how do i catch the software who is doing this?

Comment: It seems it was my GeForce software